# Listing files in a directory using list.files()

Tags: r

I am on mac OS X 10.9.4 Maverics. I am using R console to download some files (using Rstudio has no effect on my problem), version R 3.1.1, GUI 1.65 Snow Leopard build (6784). I have downloaded some data using the following code:

```
dataset_url <- "http://s3.amazonaws.com/practice_assignment/diet_data.zip" 
download.file(dataset_url, "diet_data.zip")
unzip("diet_data.zip", exdir = "diet_data")
```

Then, if I check my directory:

```
getwd()
# [1] "/Users/katarinamayer/Desktop/diet_data"
list.files("diet_data")
# character(0)
```

But if I just type:

```
list.files()
# [1] "Andy.csv"       "David.csv"      "John.csv"       "Mike.csv"       "Steve.csv"      "weightmedian.R"
```

Why I cannot get the list of my files when I specify my directory, using `list.files("diet_data")`?

Comment: This is expected behavior.  See `?list.files`.  It is because you are already in `diet_data`.  When you use `list.files("diet_data")`, `list.files` looks for the folder `diet_data` in the current directory, but can't find it because you're already in it.  `list.files()` lists the files in the current working directory.

Answer (score 9):

You are already inside the `diet_data` directory, as indicated by the output of `getwd()`. By default, `list.files()` will list the files on the path returned by `getwd()`.

If you `setwd("/Users/katarinamayer/Desktop/")`, then execute `list.files("diet_data")`, I believe you will observe the behaviour that you expect.

Comment: @mayerkat If this answered your question, you can mark it as solved by clicking the checkmark next to the answer.

Comment: @mayerkat - you also gain reputation by accepting the answer.